# Byte representation of floats in Common Lisp

Tags: floating-point, common-lisp, binary-data

I'm attempting to write something in Common Lisp to read and write data in a particular binary format, as a way of both learning Lisp and hopefully ending up with a useful (or at least interesting) tool. I started off with [the parser project in Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/practical-parsing-binary-files.html) and have been building up from there. One thing I need that's not in there is floating-point numbers of arbitrary length (in bytes). CL provides `ldb` for unsigned integers, and from there, signed ones weren't too hard to build – is there any comparable useful functionality for getting and setting the sign, exponent, and fraction components of a floating-point number? I don't want to have to use libraries for this, since part of the point is to get practice writing code, but I don't really want to spend time re-implementing what's already built-in, either.

Comment: See http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dec_fl.htm and https://github.com/marijnh/ieee-floats/ for an example of their use

Comment: the OP did ask for "floating-point numbers of arbitrary length (in bytes)"...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're reading binary formatted floats, you'll need to implement your own parser for it.
More than likely it's going to be an IEEE Floating Point encoded value. You can find all the information you need on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754

As per getting at the various components of a floating point value once it's in CL, you can use the various functions here: http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_dec_fl.htm

- decode-float
- float-radix
- float-sign
- float-digits
- float-precision
- integer-decode-float

Comment: the OP did ask for "floating-point numbers of arbitrary length (in bytes)"...